# Changing a image within a div with in a class

Tags: javascript, html

My issue is that i am trying to make a scoreboard with 5 images of stars that turn bright when the user gets a question correct. This is the class that holds the 5 images. I tried giving each an ID but I still couldn't figure it out.

```
<div class="image_line" >
    <div class="image_cell" id="1">
        <img src ="StarOff.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell" id="2">
        <img src ="StarOff.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell" id="3">
        <img src ="StarOff.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell" id="4">
        <img src ="StarOff.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell" id="5">
        <img src ="StarOff.gif" />
    </div>

</div>
```

this is the javascript I tried to use to change the image. However what I have is a variable called corret_answers that will be used to change each image based on its ID so when the user has 1 correct answer, correct_answers = 1 and then use this to change the image as the images all have ID's of 1-5 to match with this increment variable

```
document.getElementById("1").src = "StarOn.gif";
```

[Here is an image to show you a little of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwYO0.jpg)

Comment: Caleb do you not see what a silly thing you're doing? :) This is the type of question that answers itself once you take a good look at your code. Might I suggest [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for your future programming exploits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the id to the div tag, but you need to assign the id to the img tag. Then you should get the reference to the image and can then change its src:

`<div class="image_cell">
        <img src ="StarOff.gif" id="1"/>
    </div>`

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the `src` attribute of the `<div class="image_cell" id="1">`, which is non-existent. What you want to do is to access its child node (the `<img>`) instead:

```
document.getElementById("1").querySelector("img").src = "StarOn.gif";
```

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/z1fru5f0/

You need to assign your img tags the id and not the div, if you assign the divs the id then you need to check its childNodes.

Html

```
<div class="image_line" >
    <div class="image_cell">
        <img id="1" src ="http://www.gamingevolution.info/screenshots/main.php/d/149898-1/Greystar.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell">
        <img id="2" src ="http://www.gamingevolution.info/screenshots/main.php/d/149898-1/Greystar.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell">
        <img id="3" src ="http://www.gamingevolution.info/screenshots/main.php/d/149898-1/Greystar.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="4" class="image_cell">
        <img src ="http://www.gamingevolution.info/screenshots/main.php/d/149898-1/Greystar.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="5" class="image_cell">
        <img src ="http://www.gamingevolution.info/screenshots/main.php/d/149898-1/Greystar.gif" />
    </div>

</div>
```

javascript

```
var start1 = document.getElementById("1")
start1.src = "https://www.fortwhyte.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/gold_star.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `correct_answer` is a Number so I converted it to a String (using `toString`) so it can be used to match the `.image_cell` `id`. I added an `input` to demonstrate it actually functions.

See Snippet

```js
var correct_answer = 0;

function starOn(correct_answer) {
  var x = correct_answer.toString();
  var iCell = document.getElementById(x);
  var iStar = iCell.querySelector('img');
  iStar.src = "http://findicons.com/files/icons/249/xmas_pack/48/star.png";
}
```

```css
.image_cell {
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  width: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_line">
  <div class="image_cell" id="1">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-basic/yellow/star_basic_yellow.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image_cell" id="2">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-basic/yellow/star_basic_yellow.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image_cell" id="3">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-basic/yellow/star_basic_yellow.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image_cell" id="4">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-basic/yellow/star_basic_yellow.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image_cell" id="5">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-basic/yellow/star_basic_yellow.png" />
  </div>

</div>
<br/>
<label>Type in a number 1 to 5</label>
<input oninput="starOn(this.value);">
```